# use Telerik controls in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, orchardcms

I am trying to use the Telerik datetimepicker in my own module of Orchard CMS.

everything seems working well except javascript.  the datetimepicker control is unable to show the drop-down calendar.

I tried to use

```
Script.Include("~/Themes/Contoso/Scripts/2011.2.712/telerik.common.min.js").AtFoot();        

Script.Include("~/Themes/Contoso/Scripts/2011.2.712/telerik.datetimepicker.min.js").AtFoot();
```

or  created an ResourceManifest.cs in my module and called followings.

```
Script.Require("telerik_datepicker").AtFoot();
Script.Require("telerik_calendar").AtFoot();
```

I can see no run time errors against scripts i am refereing.  but no document.ready() stuff in the html source for the page.

I dont know where got wrong.  hope someone can crack the problems . thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Telerik UI components for ASP.NET MVC require a ScriptRegistrar in order to work properly. The latter outputs the required JavaScript files as well as the JavaScript initialization code. You are probably missing a ScriptRegistrar hence the DatePicker does not work. Here is the minimum required code:

```
@(Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
      .Name("DatePicker")
)

@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar())
```

Comment: It's all working fine. but do you know how to customise the control appreance?  when I look at the source,  I see Telerik add some class names for each control. for example:    <div class="display-field">  
          
        <input class="t-widget t-autocomplete t-input" id="Instrument" name="Instrument" style="width:250px" type="text" />
        
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

Don't those Telerik helpers rely on some kind of HttpModule that you'd need to register in the global config?

Comment: Not as I am aware of.  the Telerik controls works very well with normal mvc razor view project I created. No need to do any twiiks. but not able to show drop-down calendars in Orchard customized modules.